# How can a verified Google News inclusion site show in the Google search results?

Tags: google-search, search-results, google-news

We have been watching about 25-30 days long in Google SERP whenever we search in Google Search Engine with "Fifa World Cup" and "বিশ্বকাপ ফুটবল" with those Keywords then in Google SERP Google is showing a Fifa World Cup-related News Feature at the 1st position with Fifa News, Countries and Location. And only Two News portals news is showing for all the time for the (Bengali Version).

We want to know about if is there any policy to show my news portal Fifa news in this feature? Our News site is already verified by Google News inclusion. We have been publishing Fifa World Cup ralted News but not a singal news showed in the mean time.

For more please check attached screenshots.
[image]
[image]
We need the process of it.

Comment: Are you a large publisher, are you using AMP?

Comment: Yes, we are the large publisher in our country and we have also AMP.